# Need an example on the topology of compact convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Find polynomials $f,g\in \mathbb{C}[z]$ and a $K\subset\subset \mathbb{C}$ such that 
\begin{equation}
\|fg\|_K<\|f\|_K\|g\|_K
\end{equation}
where $\|f\|_K:=\sup_{t\in K}|f(t)|$.

I have tried $f=z$ and $g=-z^2+1$,$K$ being the unit disc,but it doesn't work.Can you give me a simple example?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem with that is that $\lvert f(z)\rvert \equiv 1$ on the boundary of the unit disk. Modify it a little to avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

take $K=\{0,1\}$ and polynomials $p_1=1-z$ and $p_2=z$

Notice you just needed to contruct it in way that where 
the one takes the maximum the other does not